# 2nd to last level of a directory tree

Tags: c#, file, tree, filesystems, directory

I am trying to get the 2nd to last level of the directory tree that I used an array to get.
When it gets to the Console.WriteLine part, it doesn't display anything, it seems to skip that entire line.

```
foreach (string file in files)   
{   
    string thepathoflife = Path.GetFullPath(file);
    string filetocopy = file;
    string location = file;
    bool b = false;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
    string thenameofdoom = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);


    //here is my attempt
    string dirthing = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename); //here is my attempt
    System.Console.WriteLine("" + dirthing); //here is my attempt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `Path.GetDirectoryName` twice to walk up the folder hierarchy:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetFullPath(file)))
```

It will return `null` if you are too "high" in the hierarchy.

Comment: I want to find the folder the file is in. I am using System.Console.WriteLine("" + dirthing); to see if it worked.

Comment: This works, it just took me a second to figure out what all was making it not display, it was a small typo that didn't cause an exception

Comment: Thats not what you show in your example, you show the path above.. eg c:\a\b\c.txt your example talks of c:\a as the path.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few examples:

```
var path = Path.GetFullPath("example.png");
// path == "C:\\Users\\dtb\\Desktop\\example.png"

Path.GetFileName(path)                              // "example.png"
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)              // "example"
Path.GetExtension(path)                             // ".png"

Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetFileName(path))       // ""

Path.GetDirectoryName(path)                         // "C:\\Users\\dtb\\Desktop"
Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))  // "C:\\Users\\dtb"
```

Comment: the thing is, I am using string thepathoflife = Path.GetFullPath(file); to find the full path.

Comment: @shred1894 No, actually, you're not.  You get it and then never actually use it...

Comment: I do use it, later, much later. I didnt actually give the entire 200+ line script.